# Dividing by zero results negative infinity

Tags: limits, self-learning, limits-without-lhopital

I was reading about limits and stumbled upon this [site](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/limconsoldirectory/LimConSol.html#SOLUTION%2010) and saw the author doing something funny:

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^3-7x}{x^3} $$

It is quite clear that you can apply l'Hospital at this point but the author does something else:

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x\left(x^2-7\right)}{x\left(x^2\right)} $$

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2-7x}{x^3}  = \quad'' \quad \frac{-7}{0} \quad'' = -\infty $$

I looked up indeterminate forms and could not find anything like this. What is going on here ?

With l'Hospital I dont get much farther either.

Comment: With L'Hôpital's rule you get exactly the same result.

Comment: Typo third line - an extra $x$? Note $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2-7}{x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}1-\frac{7}{x^2}=1-\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{7}{x^2}$ is another way of finishing the last line if you're not quite comfortable with what the author does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'Hospital's rule is unnecessary here, as simple algebra gets rid of the indeterminate form. Just cancel an $x$ from the top and bottom as the author does:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^3 - 7x}{x^3} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2 - 7}{x^2}.
$$
Now, when the author writes "$-7/0^+$", he's saying that the limit of the numerator is -7, and the limit of the denominator is 0, but is positive on both sides. Whenever you have a finite limit for the numerator and a 0 limit for the denominator, the limit will either be nonexistent (if the signs don't match on opposite sides) or $\pm \infty$ (if they do). In this case the denominator is positive on both sides, so, since the numerator is negative, the limit will be $-\infty$. It is this sense in which $-7/0^+ = -\infty$. Similarly, in this sense $-7/0^- = \infty$, while $-7/0$ remains undefined.

Comment: makes sense, but also feels very unorthodox, will accept in a bit, also what is this "phenomenon" called (theres gotta be a name for this, right) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what phenomenon you mean. As for the notation, it's suggestive of non-standard analysis, which, despite the name, is probably how most people handle calculus conceptually.